# Declaring a public variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When I try to move 'UserName' from local scope 'dim' to public, I get 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' What is causing this?

Going from this:

```
Dim UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
```

to this:

```
Public UserName As TextBox = DirectCast(LoginUser.FindControl("UserName"), TextBox)
```

Then accessing variable like this:

```
If (Request.Cookies("Username") IsNot Nothing) Then
    UserName.Text() = Request.Cookies("Username").Value.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: Where is that code located? Class level? Inside a method/event? If it's class level your looking for a control before it has been created - hence error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 potential problems with your code:

1. It should be `UserName.Text`  i.e. not `.Text()`
2. `Request.Cookies("Username").Value.ToString()`
      If "username" is not found in the cookie collection you will get a 
      Value of nothing.  Then you call ToString on nothing which
      gives you Object Reference error.
3. Make sure that the UserName TextBox is initalized and not nothing when 
      you try to access it.

Comment: Even with IsNot Nothing, I am still getting the object reference error.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?  Did you make sure UserName is not nothing?

Comment: VB allows adding "()" when not appropriate and omitting "()" when it is appropriate - so "UserName.Text() = ..." is allowed in VB (unfortunately).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Dave, I didn't mean to imply that the "()" were causing an error but it just bothers me to see it that way.  Typically "()" are used to allocate arrays in VB so it just looks wrong.

Comment: @RickS: I know - just thought I'd point that out - VB allows too many things which just look and feel wrong.